# Collecting items for a text based game in python

Tags: python

I am currently coding a text based adventure game and I've gotten most of it figured out except for collecting the items in each of the rooms. I keep getting an error code that says "TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'", anyone know what I am doing wrong? Here is my code so far:

```
rooms = {

        'Start Area': {'name': 'Start Area', 'move south': 'West Yard', 'move east': 'Main Courtyard', 'item': 'rock'},
        'West Yard': {'name': 'West Yard', 'move north': 'Start Area', 'item': 'necklace'},
        'Main Courtyard': {'name': 'Main Courtyard', 'move north': 'North Yard', 'move east': 'East Yard',
                           'move south': 'South Yard', 'move west': 'Start Area', 'item': 'ring'},
        'South Yard': {'name': 'South Yard', 'move north': 'Main Courtyard', 'move east': 'Maintenance Shed',
                       'item': 'pendant'},
        'Maintenance Shed': {'name': 'Maintenance Shed', 'move west': 'South Yard', 'item': 'old key'},
        'East Yard': {'name': 'East Yard', 'move west': 'Main Courtyard', 'move north': 'Main Gate',
                      'item': 'picture frame'},
        'Main Gate': {'name': 'Main Gate', 'move south': 'East Yard', 'item': 'main gate'},
        'North Yard': {'name': 'North Yard', 'move east': 'Catacombs: Entrance', 'move south': 'Main Courtyard',
                       'item': 'gate'},
        'Catacombs: Entrance': {'name': 'Catacombs: Entrance', 'move east': 'Catacombs: North Wing',
                                'move west': 'North Yard', 'item': 'bracelet'},
        'Catacombs: North Wing': {'name': 'Catacombs: North Wing', 'move west': 'Catacombs: Entrance',
                                  'move south': 'Catacombs: Main Tunnel', 'item': 'vase'},
        'Catacombs: Main Tunnel': {'name': 'Catacombs: Main Tunnel', 'move north': 'Catacombs: North Wing',
                                   'move south': 'Catacombs: South Wing', 'item': 'rusty key'},
        'Catacombs: South Wing': {'name': 'Catacombs: South Wing', 'move north': 'Catacombs: Main Tunnel',
                                  'item': 'bolt cutters'}
    }

player_room = rooms['Start Area']

directions = ['move north', 'move south', 'move east', 'move west']

how2 = ('For movement type: move north, south, east, or west\nFor actions type: collect (item)'
)

player_inv = []

prol = ('text')

ending = ('text'
          'You collected: ', player_inv)

fail = ('text')

print('Welcome to Graverobber')

print('For directions type: ?')

print('For prologue, type: prologue')

print('You enter the graveyard.')

while True:

    print('You are in the {}.'.format(player_room['name']))

    print('Your current inventory: {}\n'.format(player_inv))

    user_input = input('What would you like to do? ')
    if user_input == 'prologue':
        print(prol)
    elif user_input == '?':
        print(how2)
    elif user_input in directions:
        if user_input in player_room:
            player_room = rooms[player_room[user_input]]
            if player_room == rooms['Main Gate']:
                if 'bolt cutters' in player_inv:
                    print(ending)
                    break
                else:
                    print(fail)
                    break
            if player_room['item']:
                print('You see a {}'.format(''.join(player_room['item'])))
        else:
            print('You cannot move in that direction')
    elif user_input == 'exit':
        break
    elif user_input == ('collect ' + rooms[player_room]['item']):
        if rooms[player_room]['item'] and player_inv:
            print('You already have this item in your inventory!')
        else:
            player_inv.append(rooms[player_room][user_input])
    else:
        print('Invalid command')
```

My error code says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MrBattery101\PycharmProjects\TextBasedGame\main.py", line 80, in <module>
    elif user_input == ('collect ' + rooms[player_room]['item']):
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: Could you format your answer as code and saving syntax please.

Comment: Add the error traceback as well

Comment: I'm a bit new to python, what exactly are you asking for?

Comment: `player_room` is already an element of `rooms`.  You can't look it up again.

Comment: Okay, so where the code says `'collect ' + rooms[player_room]['item']`, what exactly do you expect that to do, *step by step*? In particular: where it says `rooms[player_room]['item']`, you understand that this means **first `rooms[player_room]` is looked up**, and then `['item']` is used as a lookup into that result. Yes? So. At this point in the code, what is `player_room`? Does it make sense to use that as a key in the `rooms` dict? Why or why not? Did you try to check that value, and make sure it makes sense? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 1):

player_room is a dict, hence you get an error when you try to use it as a key for rooms in
`rooms[player_room]...`
You will need to use a key from the dict room (for example `rooms["Start Area"]...` ) instead. What you're using in your variable player_room is the value, not the key.

Comment: How else would I identify the item associated with the room? Could I just write, if 'item' and player_inv:...?

Answer (score 0):

In

```
elif user_input == ('collect ' + rooms[player_room]['item']):
```

You are passing a `dict` as a key. You need to pass its key which is string in this case.

Comment: ah i changed to     

elif user_input == ('collect ' + player_room['item']):
        if player_room['item'] and player_inv:
            print('You already have this item in your inventory!')
        else:
            player_inv.append(player_room['item'])

this seemed to work